# Text-formating exponent numbers in RDLC Reports

Tags: text, format, rdlc, exponent

I got a RDLC-Report and I need to add the exponential formating to some numbers, so basically **[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yneSX.png)** is how it should look like.

I tried `Text^2`, searched in the `expression-menu` and even tried to copying the text from Word, but I still couldn't get it to work.

So, how does this work?

**EDIT:**

I found out about the `<sup>` HTML-tag, however when I try using them, they just get ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that I can just copy-paste the Unicode-version instead of any tags or functions.

Please note, that **I only need the numbers 1 - 3** and they can be easily found in the unicode table.

https://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character